# Redshift table sizes & flavours of

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Confused by the term 'table size' in Redshift.

We have :
**svv_table_info.size**
"Size of table in 1MB blocks"

**svv_table_info.pct_used**
"Percent of available space used"

... so I assume that a lot of the 'size' is empty space due to sort keys etc

Then we have this..
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-cluster-storage-space/

.. which uses the term **'minimum' table size.**
But nowhere can I find an explanation of what they means in the real world ? Is this a theoretical minimum if optimally configured ?

Ultimately I need to find out the basic size of original tangible data without any overheads.

Then yes, how much disc space is it actually costing to store it in Redshift.

So if I took 1TB out of our on-prem database and shoved it into Redshift, I'd be looking to see something like 1TB (data) & 1.2TB  (data + Redshift overheads).

Hope someone can help clarify

Comment: Your linked page defines the minimum table size as `Minimum table size = block_size (1 MB) * (number_of_user_columns + 3 system columns) * number_of_populated_slices * number_of_table_segments`. That's a pretty clear definition.

Comment: So put it this way, why is size from svv_table_info different to the linked calculation? Is one theoretical and one actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift stores data in 1MB blocks and blocks are associated with a slice and a column.  So if I have 2 slices in my cluster and a table with 4 columns (plus the 3 system columns to make 7) distributed as EVEN containing at least 2 rows, then my table will minimally take up 2 X 7 X 1MB of space (14MB on disk).  This is all that article is saying.

Now if I insert 2 additional rows into this table, Redshift will makes new blocks for this data.  So now my 4 rows of data take up 28MB of space.  However, if I Vacuum the table the wasted space will be reclaimed and the table size will come back down to 14MB.  (yes this is a bit of an oversimplification but trying to get the concepts across)

As a rule of thumb a single 1MB block will typically hold between 100,000 rows and 2,000,000 rows of compressed data.  (yes this depends on the data not being monster varchars)  So for our table above I can keep adding rows (and vacuuming) without increasing the table size on disk until I get a few hundred thousand rows (per slice) in the table.  Redshift is very efficient at storing large chunks of data but very inefficient at storing small ones.

What Redshift knows about your data size is how many blocks it takes on disk (across all the nodes, slices, and columns).  How big your data would be if it was stored differently (not in blocks, compressed or uncompressed) is not data that is tracked. As John noted, for big tables, Redshift stores data more efficiently than most other database (when compression is used).

Comment: Bill, that's, that's helped a lot. So in your example, you had 2 initial rows, then added 2 more. svv_table_info at that stage would tell me 28MB, and the 'minimal size' calculation would say 14MB? After vacuum, svv_table_info would come back down to14MB?

Comment: Correct.  Redshift blocks are immutable and once written never change (copied, modified, and replaced) (again oversimplified).  This is why it is so important to write to Redshift in large chunks, infrequently (5min vs 100msec).  Now remember that there could be several versions of the same block on the system because multiple sessions are modifying the same block.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot translate from an existing database size to the size of a table in Redshift. This is because:

- Columns are stored separately
- Minimum block size is 1MB
- Data in Redshift is compressed, so it can take considerably less space depending on the type of data and the compression type chosen

Given compression, your data is likely to be *smaller* in Redshift than an original (uncompressed) data source. However, you can't really calculate that in advance unless you have transferred similar data in the past and apply a similar ratio.

Comment: Sure, I get that, maybe my example was poor. Let's say i have 0.5MB of data, Redshift stores it in a 1MB block. So I'm looking to report 0.5MB as 'data size' and 1MB as 'disc size'. Looking at svv_table_info I am assuming that it will tell me my size is 1MB, and pct_used 0.5 ? And if that's right, where does the 'minimal' calculation come into play?